# Removing items from context menu of edittext

Tags: java, android

I saw similar question but nobody answered how to actually remove items from edittext's context menu. So when I long click edittext I have my items that I created, but there is some additional items that I don't want to appear, like: Select word, select all, something with dictionary etc.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.white:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "white", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.red:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "red", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.green:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "green", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Comment: What does the menu xml look like? in res/menu/context.xml (most likely). You probably have the extra options in here

Comment: @ELFik I deleted all extra items if that's what you said. But it's default context menu for editText, it appears when no other context menu is defined.. 

http://s28.postimg.org/9ak66i8fx/image.jpg